# How to add json object to hive flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I have the next problem: add my data to the hive flutter
my data is following:

```
Author_1, links, (articles_1, articles_2, ..., articles_N),
Author_2, links, (articles_1, articles_2, ..., articles_N)
Author_3, links, (articles_1, articles_2, ..., articles_N)
```

That is, all my data consists of the name of the authors, links and articles. But each author has more than one article and therefore I had a problem and I don’t understand how to implement it in the hive flutter, please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do You know how save model into hive? if no, [enter link description here](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/type_adapters) if yes,  so with register your model to hive, hive knows your model as data type that you can save objects like that, now that's how I understand it, your model consist of `String author`, `String link`, `List<String> article`, so build this is model and after register to hive, save your model objects into that

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Paper {
  Paper({
    this.author,
    this.link,
    this.articles,
  });

  @HiveField(0)
  final String? author;
  @HiveField(1)
  final String? link;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String? articles;

  factory Paper.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Paper(author: json['author'], link:json['link'], articles:json['articles'])
  
}

class PaperAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Paper> {
  @override
  int get typeId => 0;

  @override
  Paper read(BinaryReader reader) {
    int numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    Map fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };

    return Paper(
      author: fields[0],
      link: fields[1],
      articles: fields[2],
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Paper obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.author)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.link)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.articles);
  }
}
```

after that `Hive.registerAdapter(PaperAdapter());` then easily `var box = await Hive.openBox<Paper>('paperBox');  box.add(Paper(author:'a', link:'b', articles:['aa', 'bb']));`

Comment: I have read this article, thanks. I don't understand how can I add data so that I add for example 100 names of authors to each of which has one link and several articles

Comment: Thanks friend, I'll try now. I thought to make my data in json first. My data is now in a non-normalized form in the Sqflite and I need to add it from the skylight to the hive, thanks, now I'll try your option!

Comment: your welcome, please can ticking as the correct answer

Comment: I also edited answer for parse json

Comment: Yes friend, i picked correct answer.

Comment: Say me please, is there a visualization tool for hive flutter?

Comment: And where is the data stored in the hive? Is there a hive database file in the project, such as a SQflite, that can be taken from the project?

Comment: Answer to your question in this https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/more/browser

Comment: I have seen that. Isn't this for a web application database? I have a mobile app

Comment: Yes and also told, in mobile app, hive written in files

Comment: and what is the path of the hive file in my flutter project?

Comment: My friend, why did you remove my correct answer?

Comment: My friend, I'm sorry, I accidentally! Returned the correct answer! Moved to chat! Please tell me how can I visualize my hive data, I tried index db but it doesn't work. or add me in telegram: Skywalker5489. Help me please friend

Comment: Hive is noSql and I think you can't visualize that

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Users extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String name;
  @HiveField(1)
  final String surname;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String age;

  Users(this.name, this.surname, this.age);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$name -- $surname -- $age';
  }
}
```

//you should use  packages build_runner: ^versions
hive_generator: ^versions and you should creat typeadpter class